# password encryption nodeJS PBKDF2

Tags: node.js, encryption, asp.net-identity

We are moving from asp.net to nodeJS and user's password were in hash that was generated by default ASP.net encryption, so 1st problem was how to match user password with hash password is solved in following code and this working perfectly But now i am stuck how to generate same kind hash for new users ?

```
    // NodeJS implementation of crypto, I'm sure google's 
// cryptoJS would work equally well.
var crypto = require('crypto');

// The value stored in [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[PasswordHash]
var hashedPwd = "ADOEtXqGCnWCuuc5UOAVIvMVJWjANOA/LoVy0E4XCyUHIfJ7dfSY0Id+uJ20DTtG+A==";
var hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');

var hexChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var saltString = "";
var storedSubKeyString = "";

// build strings of octets for the salt and the stored key
for (var i = 1; i < hashedPasswordBytes.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= 16) {
        saltString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f]
    }
    if (i > 0 && i > 16) {
        storedSubKeyString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f];
    }
}

// password provided by the user
var password = 'welcome1';

// TODO remove debug - logging passwords in prod is considered 
// tasteless for some odd reason
console.log('cleartext: ' + password);
console.log('saltString: ' + saltString);
console.log('storedSubKeyString: ' + storedSubKeyString);

// This is where the magic happens. 
// If you are doing your own hashing, you can (and maybe should)
// perform more iterations of applying the salt and perhaps
// use a stronger hash than sha1, but if you want it to work
// with the [as of 2015] Microsoft Identity framework, keep
// these settings.
var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 256, 'sha1');

// get a hex string of the derived bytes
var derivedKeyOctets = nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();

console.log("hex of derived key octets: " + derivedKeyOctets);

// The first 64 bytes of the derived key should
// match the stored sub key
if (derivedKeyOctets.indexOf(storedSubKeyString) === 0) {
    console.info("passwords match!");
} else {
    console.warn("passwords DO NOT match!");
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "generate this hash password." You assign the raw password to `password` and `derivedKeyOctets` will be the result. What other generating did you have in mind?

Comment: actually i want to encrypt raw password into hash. 

we are moving asp to nodeJS, we don't want our users to change password, so we need solution to match password with hashed password and above code is perfectly working, but what about new user how to generate same hashing password for them ?

Comment: The password hash looks like the v2 format, documented in C# here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

Comment: hi, solved my problem and answered, thanks for your time @rob

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, Code for encrypt is :

```
salt = '1234123412341234';
saltString = new Buffer(salt).toString('hex');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var password = 'welcome';

var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 32, 'sha1');

var hashInHex="00"+saltString+nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();
var FinalHash = Buffer.from(hashInHex, 'hex').toString('base64')
console.log("newhash: "+FinalHash);
console.log("salt: "+saltString);
```

thanks